# Can I use an XBAP in a ASP.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xbap

The problem I started with is that I want to display in an ASP.NET application a 3D model.

First of all I thought of Silverlight, but Silverlight 3 does not support 3D rendering. WPF does, so the next step was creating a demo for an WPF browser application.

The 3D surface was rendered, but how can I include it in the APS.NET application? Furthermore, what would the web server need to have installed in order to load and run the XBAP? Is there any way that I can access from the XBAP server objects like Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed an XBAP directly in HTML, but you can put it in an IFRAME. The server doesn't need anything specific, the XBAP will run entirely on the client. You can even deploy it on a Linux server with Apache...